# How to make a circular pattern dent on a mesh

Tags: sculpting

I'm trying to make circular dent pattern on a mesh. I'm using the sculpt mode making each individual circular dent, and it's extremely time consuming. What's the correct method to achieve this? I also tried creating a pattern Alpha brush, but It's not working correctly for me.

Ideally I'd like to import my Alpha brush, and with a click those circle shapes would appear on the mesh.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sculpt it, but if the object shape allows it, it would be even simpler to use a *Displace* modifier to project the pattern, subdivide your object enough, use a *Smooth* modifier if necessary (but the holes will loose their sharpness):

[image]

Also you could use a higher resolution image: Open your image in Krita, convert to 16 or 32-bit float, scale it up, blur, save, and use this new image:

[image]

Comment: How did you get the circle holes so smooth? I subdivided my mesh 5 times, and the holes still have ugly edges.

https://ibb.co/r4ybQ03
https://ibb.co/vz4x3GD

Comment: The more it will be subdivided before the Displace modifier the smoother it will be, also your image is rather low-resolution, you should open it in Photoshop or Krita, scale up its size, blur a bit, and use this new image

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation, I will be experimenting more with this new method.

https://ibb.co/vv5vj4k